# My Batch script would not output the result of my .exe file into a .txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to run a .exe file from my batch script and store the output into a separate .txt file

```
@echo off
(
time/t
date/t
systeminfo
ipconfig/all
net user
net group
route print
arp -a
ipconfig/displaydns
netstat -n
)> output.txt

start /B /wait EDD.exe >>eddoutput.txt

pause
```

I want to run the first set of commands and put them in `output.txt` and run the .exe file and output the results/contents of that file into another txt document.

Comment: I only see one command and a pause statement, where are your sets of commands? This site is for help with problematic code, but you have not told us what the posted code does not do, which it was supposed to do. As such your question is currently off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: fixed the code.

Comment: Get rid of the `start /b /wait`.